# estructura de un arreglo tipo texto en php

Tags: php, array, json

Buenas noches necesito  hacer un arreglo de nueve elementos tipo texto, cada  uno de ellos representa un punto de venta y cada uno  tiene la propiedad de dirección, altitud y longitud, para despues convertirlo a json mediante json_encode(), no se si la estructura se encuentre bien, por lo que eh visto es que en el archivo json devuelve el resultado en este tipo de estructura {"Masculino": "Masculino"," Musculino "}

```
      <?php
      $arreglo = array("MATEO BENITEZ 89 COL. centro TUXTEPEC MEXICO CP 38500 latitud 
      20.48871324385829, longitud -100.65457702572893","JOSEFINA ENRIQUEZ 102   COL. CENTRO 
      TUXTEPEC CP 68300 latitud 20.48871324385829, longitud -100.65457702572893
      AGUSTINA CARRERA 96   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC    CP 68300 latitud 20.48871324385829, 
      longitud -100.65457702572893");

      sort($arreglo);



     for($a=0;$a<count($arreglo);$a++){
    // echo $arreglo[$a];
   // echo'<br>';
   }



    $json_string = json_encode($arreglo);
    $file = 'res.json';
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
    echo $json_string;
    echo '<br>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Yo tendría un array de objetos puntos de venta y cada objeto con las propiedades dirección, longitud y latitud quedando algo como `[{direccion: 'MATEO BENITEZ 89 COL. centro TUXTEPEC MEXICO CP 38500', latitud: '20.48871324385829', longitud: '-100.65457702572893'}, {direccion: 'JOSEFINA ENRIQUEZ 102   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC CP 68300', latitud: '20.48871324385829', longitud: '-100.65457702572893'}]`. Aunque realmente es cuestión de opiniones y de lo que vayas a querer hacer luego con esos datos.

Comment: gracias, lo que quiero hacer con esos datos es imprimirlos en un html  y tomar los valores latitud y longitud para agregar una funcion que me permita verlos en google maps

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo realmente defines el arreglo con un único elemento, un texto con todos los datos que dices. La forma de crear un arreglo como quieres, con registros punto de venta, latitud, longitud sería algo así:

```
$arreglo = array(
      ['pv'=>"MATEO BENITEZ 89 COL. centro TUXTEPEC MEXICO CP 38500", 'latitud'=>20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=> -100.65457702572893],
      ['pv'=>"JOSEFINA ENRIQUEZ 102   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC CP 68300", 'latitud'=>20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=> -100.65457702572893],
      ['pv'=>"AGUSTINA CARRERA 96   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC    CP 68300", 'latitud'=> 20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=>-100.65457702572893]);
```

Ahora tu arreglo[0].pv contendrá MATEO BENITEZ....
Y, como podrás observar si pruebas esta solución, el JSON que se crea tiene la foma que dices: {"pv":"AGUSTINA CARRERA 96   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC...

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes hacer es definir un array asociativo con:

```
$arreglo = [
    "punto_venta_1" => [
        "direccion" => "prueba", 
        "altitud" => 2,
        "longitud" => 3
    ],
    "punto_venta_2" => [
        "direccion" => "prueba2", 
        "altitud" => 2,
        "longitud" => 3
    ],
];
```

Y a `$arreglo` hacer el posterior json_encode.

Comment: Muchas gracias!